# Example of multi label, multi class(multi output) RandomForest & Nearest Neighbor in scikit-learn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, neural-network, random-forest

could someone post a basic example of what a multi output, multi class  RandomForest Classifier and Nearest Neighbor algorithm looks like?  They are supported out of the box, but I do not know how to use them as the docs are too abstract to me.

Essentially, what do I have to do to access the multilabel properties of the classifer?  I already have my `Y` labels in a `list()` format as shown below. I have also transformed my labels:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer
mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
YC = mlb.fit_transform(df['combined_atc'].astype(str))
```

Dataset snippet:

```
X1   X2     X3        Y
red  NaN    NaN       [candy, pen]
red  green  blue      [clown, rainbow]
red  yellow NaN       [sun, car, shirt]
yello pink  black     [shirt, car]
```

As long as I can predict one of the items in Y, I'm "correct".
So if I had an X1 of "red" then if I said "candy" or "pen" or "candy and pen" then I'm correct. There is no inherent ordering and it wouldn't matter.

Is this a multiple label, multiple class problem?  What would be the ideal algorithm to use here? Anything out of the box support my use case?

```
import pandas
from sklearn import model_selection
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier


rf = RandomForestClassifier(n_jobs=2)#use 2 cores
seed=7
max_features = 'auto'
num_trees = 2

kfold = model_selection.KFold(n_splits=3, random_state=seed)

model = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=num_trees, 
max_features=max_features, verbose=1)

results = model_selection.cross_val_score(model, X, YC, cv=kfold)
print(results.mean())
```

Comment: This matches the multilabel classification. See the [scikit documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/multiclass.html). Not the Multioutput-multiclass which you are saying.

Comment: multiple label and multiple class are two different problems. In the linked document in my above comment, you can get which estimators are suitable for what kind of task.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you presented is indeed a multi-label multi-class problem. In `scikit-learn`, `Decision Trees`, `Random Forests`, `Nearest Neighbors` support mulit-label multi-class problems out-of-the-box.

Other approach would be to build a model for every unique label in your dataset. Thus converting the problem to a binary classification problem for *each* label.

If you want to create a custom evaluation function as you mentioned you can use `metrics.make_scorer`